# Kubernetes Ingress - Ingress to service routing not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a ingress like the below one.

> kubectl get ing test-ingress -o yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"tectonic"},"name":"test-ingress","namespace":"nstest"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"test.nstest.k8s.privatecloud.com","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"test","servicePort":8080},"path":"/"}]}}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: tectonic
  creationTimestamp: 2018-03-27T17:57:02Z
  generation: 1
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: "nstest"
  resourceVersion: "19985087"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/nstest/ingresses/test-ingress
  uid: 4100bd04-31e8-11e8-8f7b-5cb9018ebebc
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.nstest.k8s.privatecloud.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

My service is as follows,

> kubectl get svc test -o yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"test"},"name":"test","namespace":"nstest"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":8080,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8080}],"selector":{"app":"test"}}}
  creationTimestamp: 2018-03-27T17:57:02Z
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
  namespace: "nstest"
  resourceVersion: "19985067"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/nstest/services/test
  uid: 40f975f3-31e8-11e8-8f7b-5cb9018ebebc
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.158.50.20
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: test
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The pods are running fine. What is wrong with this? Why the routing from ingress to service not working.

Error on accessing ingress endpoint,

> ```
> Ingress Error
> No healthy backends could be found.
> Check pod liveness probes for more details.
> ```

Thanks,

Comment: what is the `CrashLoopBackOff` and/or `Ready` status of your Pods? The error message makes it seem that `kubectl get pods -a -l app=test` is unwell (actually, I guess that message may imply the actual Ingress controllers are unwell, but let's start with the Service's Pods)

Answer (score 4):

You should give the port in your Service spec a "name", and refer to that in your Ingress:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myApp
spec:
  selector:
    app: myApp
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myApp
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myApp
          servicePort: http
```

Answer (score -1):

In the Dockerfile, you need to export a port (to which the server is listening, say 8080) like this:

```
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
```

In your deployment, you need to specify the `containerPort` as 8080.